# PC IP address to location coordinates

Tags: c++, location, ip, coordinates

I wonder if it's possible to get longitude, latitude and altitude based on my machine(P.C, Laptop and so on) I.P address using C++. Not PHP or any third party website. I want to hear suggestions and How would it be possible.

Answer (score 1):

That is not possible. Without knowing who the IP address belongs to (and you can't know that), you can't get any further information than the IP address itself. There is no (direct) correlation between IP addresses and location. For example, AOL (do they still exist) may give out the same range of 16 Million IP addresses in the UK, USA and France, if they wish.

Comment: You are right. Assuming that the question is about approximated geo-locating, it's fine to live with this inaccuracy. (It's the best we can get, and it's the best third party websites can do, too)

Comment: Ah! that sucks. I wanted to get location coordinates based on my IP address. what if i use a third party program. would that be accurate enough?

Comment: accurate enough for what? The IP address to geolocation will give you "town" at the very best - and could be VERY wrong at worst - partly, it would depend on who provided the data - technically, the ISP or whoever provides the IP address will know EXACTLY [except for mobile devices of course]. What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

This is not related to *programming* I think. Once you have a database with enough data, you are free to query this database with any language you want.

So it's a matter of the database you are using. Have a look at http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/geolite for example, which is just what I found using google (no personal recommendation).

Make sure your application pulls updates regularly to keep it up to date.

Keep in mind that *geo-locating*, which is what you are trying to do here, is only an approximation and as Mats Petersson pointed out in his answer, it can be totally incorrect.

Comment: I tried looking up my home IP address. By google maps route it is 74 miles (110km) "off". The IP address on my mobile phone is 186 miles (300km) away, in the middle of nowhere. 

I also looked up a website that I know, which gave a distance of about 1 mile (1.6km). 

When I check my works firewall address, it gives the same 54 degrees north, 2 degrees west that my mobile gives, and that's definitely not the 10 miles south of where I live, so about 196 miles (320km) wrong. 

There may be other databases with more precision, but like I said before, it's not VERY accurate...